# Hide the bottom row in UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

I create an UIActivityViewController like this

```
UIActivityViewController* activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:sharingItems applicationActivities:nil];

[activityController setExcludedActivityTypes:
 @[UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
   UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,
   UIActivityTypePrint,
   UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
   UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
   UIActivityTypeAirDrop,
   @"com.apple.reminders.RemindersEditorExtension",
   @"com.apple.mobilenotes.SharingExtension",
   ]];
```

Now, the action sheet that pops up has 0 items (except for More) in the bottom line, still that line is visible. Is there any way to remove that line altogether?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To hide line you have to hide the more button and that is not possible that enables user to reorder.

> In iOS 8, UIActivityViewController is still an API that only provides
>   custom functions, but not custom UI. You can't change the way it
>   looks. The only part of the visual style you can change is the icon of
>   your custom UIActivity subclasses.

But if you really want to hide you can use third party lib available .

- [OvershareKit](https://github.com/overshare/overshare-kit)
- [URBNShareKit](https://github.com/urbn/URBNShareKit)